# Difference in printing the Nth line with sed vs while ... read?

Tags: bash

```
$ cat inputfile| while read i ;do echo ${#i}; done
12550
12972
13035
... snip
0
$ for i in {1..21} ; do sed -n "$i"p inputfile |wc -c ; done
13226
13680
13759
... snip
1
```

The input file contains 21 JSON objects concatenated together. Trying to feed each to jq errors on the first while it works with the second. There's clearly a difference but what?

(The output of both loops is 21 line long.)

Comment: for bigger files, second is more efficient as `awk '{print length}' inputfile` (or `length+1`)

Answer (score 1):

`read` by default trims leading and trailing whitespace and consumes backslashes. You can disable those by setting `IFS` to empty string and specifying the `-r` flag, respectively. See:

```
$ echo ' \" ' | while read i; do echo ${#i}; done
1
$ echo ' \" ' | while IFS= read i; do echo ${#i}; done
3
$ echo ' \" ' | while read -r i; do echo ${#i}; done
2
$ echo ' \" ' | while IFS= read -r i; do echo ${#i}; done
4
```

Note that `wc -c` would print `5` but that's not an error. `wc` counts the terminating newline too while `read` always trims it.